# How can I migrate code using Python2's DictMixin to Python3?

Tags: python, dictmixin

I'm trying to modify some Python 2 code for Python 3.  The code imports `DictMixin`.  Is there a way to import this into Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

The `DictMixin` class is no longer available in Python3.

The [recommended solution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html?highlight=dictmixin#UserDict.DictMixin) is to subclass [collections.abc.MutableMapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) instead.

As with the `DictMixin` class, your class will need to implement some methods itself for the subclassing to work.

```
>>> class C(MutableMapping, object):pass
... 
>>> c = C()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods __delitem__, __getitem__, __iter__, __len__, __setitem__
```